# QtGui.QTableView shows data in background while a cell being edited (PyQt4)

Tags: python, background, pyqt, qtableview, cells

I get this behavior only on linux. On windows this problem does not happen.

I have a table using the model/view framework. One of the columns is editable, and when I enter it to change the data the old data is still visible in the background while I edit the data in the foreground.

I'm not sure what is causing this, I've tried flipping various settings, but  I've been unable to change the behavior.

Maybe a simpler question that will still help me: I'm correct to be looking in the view code for this issue correct? Would the model possibly have anything to do with this? Do I need to set any currently editing flags in the model?

Assuming that the view is where the issue is here is most of the view logic I'm using. There are some caveats to the following code: I'm injecting common code used between QTableViews and QTreeViews, so there are a few functions this class has that are no explicitly listed as methods:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from guitool.__PYQT__ import QtCore, QtGui
from guitool import api_item_view
from guitool.guitool_decorators import signal_, slot_

API_VIEW_BASE = QtGui.QTableView    

class APITableView(API_VIEW_BASE):
    rows_updated = signal_(str, int)
    contextMenuClicked = signal_(QtCore.QModelIndex, QtCore.QPoint)
    API_VIEW_BASE = API_VIEW_BASE

    def __init__(view, parent=None):
        API_VIEW_BASE.__init__(view, parent)
        api_item_view.injectviewinstance(view)
        view._init_table_behavior()
        view._init_header_behavior()
        view.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        view.customContextMenuRequested.connect(view.on_customMenuRequested)

    #---------------
    # Initialization
    #---------------

    def _init_table_behavior(view):
        view.setCornerButtonEnabled(False)
        view.setWordWrap(True)
        view.setSortingEnabled(True)
        view.setShowGrid(True)

        # Selection behavior            #view.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectColumns)
        view.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectItems)

        view._defaultEditTriggers = QtGui.QAbstractItemView.AllEditTriggers
        view.setEditTriggers(view._defaultEditTriggers)    
        view.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(64, 64))

    def _init_header_behavior(view):
        """ Header behavior """
        # Row Headers
        verticalHeader = view.verticalHeader()
        verticalHeader.setVisible(True)
        #verticalHeader.setSortIndicatorShown(True)
        verticalHeader.setHighlightSections(True)
        verticalHeader.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Interactive)
        verticalHeader.setMovable(True)

        # Column headers
        horizontalHeader = view.horizontalHeader()
        horizontalHeader.setVisible(True)
        horizontalHeader.setStretchLastSection(True)
        horizontalHeader.setSortIndicatorShown(True)
        horizontalHeader.setHighlightSections(True)
        # Column Sizes
        # DO NOT USE ResizeToContents. IT MAKES THINGS VERY SLOW
        #horizontalHeader.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        #horizontalHeader.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        horizontalHeader.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Interactive)
        #horizontalHeader.setCascadingSectionResizes(True)
        # Columns moveable
        horizontalHeader.setMovable(True)

    #---------------
    # Qt Overrides
    #---------------

    def setModel(view, model):
        """ QtOverride: Returns item delegate for this index """
        api_item_view.setModel(view, model)

    def keyPressEvent(view, event):
        assert isinstance(event, QtGui.QKeyEvent)
        API_VIEW_BASE.keyPressEvent(view, event)
        if event.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy):
            #print('Received Ctrl+C in View')
            view.copy_selection_to_clipboard()
        #print ('[view] keyPressEvent: %s' % event.key())

    def mouseMoveEvent(view, event):
        assert isinstance(event, QtGui.QMouseEvent)
        API_VIEW_BASE.mouseMoveEvent(view, event)

    def mousePressEvent(view, event):
        assert isinstance(event, QtGui.QMouseEvent)
        API_VIEW_BASE.mousePressEvent(view, event)
        #print('no editing')
        view.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(view, event):
        assert isinstance(event, QtGui.QMouseEvent)
        #print('editing ok')
        view.setEditTriggers(view._defaultEditTriggers)
        API_VIEW_BASE.mouseReleaseEvent(view, event)

    def clearSelection(view, *args, **kwargs):
        print('[table_view] clear selection')
        API_VIEW_BASE.clearSelection(view, *args, **kwargs)

    #---------------
    # Slots
    #---------------

    @slot_(str, int)
    def on_rows_updated(view, tblname, num):
        # re-emit the model signal
        view.rows_updated.emit(tblname, num)

    @slot_(QtCore.QPoint)
    def on_customMenuRequested(view, pos):
        index = view.indexAt(pos)
        view.contextMenuClicked.emit(index, pos)

# ----
# Injected funcs from api_item_view 

@register_view_method
def infer_delegates(view, **headers):
    """ Infers which columns should be given item delegates """
    get_thumb_size = headers.get('get_thumb_size', None)
    col_type_list  = headers.get('col_type_list', [])
    num_cols = view.model().columnCount()
    num_duplicates = int(num_cols / len(col_type_list))
    col_type_list = col_type_list * num_duplicates
    for colx, coltype in enumerate(col_type_list):
        if coltype in  qtype.QT_PIXMAP_TYPES:
            if VERBOSE:
                print('[view] colx=%r is a PIXMAP' % colx)
            thumb_delegate = APIThumbDelegate(view, get_thumb_size)
            view.setItemDelegateForColumn(colx, thumb_delegate)
        elif coltype in qtype.QT_BUTTON_TYPES:
            if VERBOSE:
                print('[view] colx=%r is a BUTTON' % colx)
            button_delegate = APIButtonDelegate(view)
            view.setItemDelegateForColumn(colx, button_delegate)
        else:
            if VERBOSE:
                print('[view] colx=%r does not have a delgate' % colx)


@register_view_method
def set_column_persistant_editor(view, column):
    """ Set each row in a column as persistant """
    num_rows = view.model.rowCount()
    print('view.set_persistant: %r rows' % num_rows)
    for row in range(num_rows):
        index  = view.model.index(row, column)
        view.view.openPersistentEditor(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

The item-delegate editor needs to paint its own background:

```
    editor.setAutoFillBackground(True)
```

Obviously, this has to be fixed within the custom delegate classes (`APIThumbDelegate` and/or `APIButtonDelegate`) which create the editor widgets (i.e. via their [`createEditor`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html#createEditor) functions).